# Create users groups in Django with different permissions

Tags: django, decorator

I need to create some users groups and create some html pages which only being member of that group will be allowed to open.
A kind of @staff_member_required decorator..
Anyone can guide me how to do it? Let's say users are members of group A-B-C.. How to write this function to open pages A-B-C?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own decorator, you can use this snippet @group_required

https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1703/

Simple make a file decorators.py and put the function, there you can make your future decorators. And then import it to your views.

Here is a good tutorial of how decorators work.

http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/